# NAS Storage or Server

Tags: wireless-networking, raid, nas, dropbox, storage

I have been looking around for alternatives to dropbox to store large amounts of pictures between multiple computers. Right now I have about 20 different computers connected to 1 Dropbox account, but they are always accessing dropbox from the same WiFi connection. So I was looking into NAS Storage like a terastation or other options for having bulk storage between various computer connections. These seem like options for personal use and may have trouble handling 20 active connections pushing data throughout the day.

My question really is, should I be looking towards server storage to handle the amount of active traffic to the storage device?

And if not server storage, does it really depend on the network for the amount of traffic a NAS storage device can handle?

I am familiar with setting up and maintaining a server, might have to do a little more research on RAID but I just dont have knowledge on recommended hardware for this purpose. To be as specific as possible, All of these computers are Mac with the exception of one windows computer. All help is very appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is mostly an opinion based question, be careful with that here. NAS devices are, literally by name, made to serve as storage attached to your network. A NAS generally doesn't have many moving parts, making it relatively easy to build and maintain one. However, there are some consumer grade products that are out-of-the-box ready and often provide an easy to understand user interface. One name brand that comes to mind is Synology: https://www.synology.com/en-us/solution/mac

Comment: thanks root, I edited the question to sound less opinion-based, I was just thinking I am completely capable of researching hardware on my own. I really need to now if NAS is capable to handle the traffic throughput or if I should be looking towards a server style storage solution. The recommendation is always appreciated though!

Comment: Synology gives you Cloud Backup to Dropbox, so I'd continue to do that from Synology. The rest can connect to your NAS. What's good about using LAN is that all the traffic remains local which will be much faster than uploading to Dropbox first, then getting distributed via LAN Sync afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if these 20 computers are all on the same LAN or not.  If yes, then it definitely makes sense to have storage that is also on your LAN.  If no, then some sort of cloud-based storage would be better.

NAS devices come in different levels of robustness, so if you go that direction, it's just a matter of shopping for one that meets your needs.  There are dedicated NAS devices, or you could also just set up a regular computer with some disk drives and use it as a storage server.  The factors you need to weigh are basically how much is your budget, and how much work are you willing to do in setting it up and maintaining it.

Comment: They are al connected to the same network, which is why I want to push away from cloud storage, which is what I am using now. Budget is not too much of an issue as long its not over like $1500, and I am very open to putting the work into it as I want to make sure it will work and if any of the drives crash I will not lose data, and from what ive been finding on the internet setting up a server with RAID 5 or 6 would be the best setup for growth as I may start with about 4 terabytes, but may need to up that to about 8-12 terabytes in another year and if a drive crashes I can hot swap a new one.

Answer (score 0):

NAS or Server. To answer this really depends on your needs. Because of what you described in your question. You would be perfectly fine with just a NAS. However, now the caveat with NAS, is limiting who can and can't access the NAS. You can limit people using MAC or IP filtering if the router allows it and thats it. It's either they get access to upload/download or they don't.

If you have a server, you could do all kinds of things with the storage as well as defrag the external storage HDD. If its not SSD that is. Important factor to consider when getting NAS too, if its not SSD, you will need to take it offline every so often and defrag the drive to keep it running optimally.

So, the question is, do you need something that provides what you want and includes all kinds of bells and whistles, which you most likely don't need or will use. Or do you just need something to just store everything but letting all your devices on the network have access to it. Also, network traffic won't be an issue too much because 20 machines uploading/downloading files on a NAS vs 20 machines uploading/downloading files on a server, would approximately be about the same performance wise given the NAS and server nic's perform at the same speeds.

In one of your comments you were worried about crashes. You can have buy Dedicated NAS systems. Which allow you to do quite few more useful things, while keeping the simple NAS ways. And if I recall you could get a NAS enclosure that could allow raid setup.